# Changing font size and text color of an element using arrow functions and addEventListener

Tags: javascript, function, dom, addeventlistener

I want to change the color and the size of the text within the h1 element on a button click. The values (color, font size) are input values. I don't know where I got it wrong, but the following code is not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Advanced functions</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id = "text">Change me, please!</h1>
    <label>Text size</label>
    <input type = "number" id = "textSize"><br>
    <label>Text color</label> 
    <input type = "color" id = "textColor"><br>
    <input type = "button" id = "btn" value = "Submit">

    <script src = "exercise2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to use arrow functions, that I will call in the eventListener.

```
let fontSelect = document.querySelector('#textSize').value;
let colorSelect = document.querySelector('#textColor').value;
let elementSelect = document.querySelector('#text');
let btn = document.querySelector("#btn");

let addSize = (element, fontSize) => element.style.fontSize = `${fontSize}px`;
let addColor = (element, color) => element.style.color = color;

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    addColor(elementSelect, colorSelect);
    addSize(elementSelect, fontSelect);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `fontSelect` and a `colorSelect` variable, which are initialized to the actual value of the respective tags, however, they never change. You need to do something like:

```
let fontSelect = document.querySelector('#textSize');
let colorSelect = document.querySelector('#textColor');
let elementSelect = document.querySelector('#text');
let btn = document.querySelector("#btn");

let addSize = (element, fontSize) => element.style.fontSize = `${fontSize}px`;
let addColor = (element, color) => element.style.color = color;

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    addColor(elementSelect, colorSelect.value);
    addSize(elementSelect, fontSelect.value);
})
```